# Does windows console output characters from locale codepage, but not from a codepage returned by GetConsoleOutputCP function?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

Here's a simple code to start with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main ()
{
    unsigned char str [3];

    printf ("LC_ALL:\t\t%s\n", setlocale (LC_ALL, ""));
    printf ("LC_TYPE:\t%s\n", setlocale (LC_CTYPE, ""));

    printf ("Input CP:\t%d\n", GetConsoleCP ());
    printf ("Output CP:\t%d\n\n", GetConsoleOutputCP ());

    str [0] = getchar ();
    str [1] = getchar ();
    str [2] = getchar ();

    printf ("%d %d %d\n", str[0], str[1], str[2]);
    printf ("%c %c %c\n", str[0], str[1], str[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Returned locale and encoding are represented on the picture. Let's say I input some small string: "пр", then press enter. What I expect are codes from OEM 866 encoding for 'п' and 'р', then 10 pointing at the end of the line, so the output codes are "175 224 10" - because console input encoding is 866, as returned by `GetConsoleCP ()`. And I get what I expect.

[image: Console output]

Then I'm trying to output these characters to the console. What I expect are the same characters from input, because, as returned by 'GetConsoleOutputCP ()', the output encoding is 866. What I get are the characters from Windows-1251 encoding, which is returned by `setlocale` function.

So, does windows console output characters from locale codepage, but not from a codepage returned by `GetConsoleOutputCP ()` function?